# Second query not working in MYSQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger

I have crated a trigger to copy row from "tblt_timesheet" to "MYTABLE" then delete row from tblt_timesheet.

copy row working but, delete row from tblt_timesheet not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
AFTER INSERT ON `tblt_timesheet`

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (NEW.timesheetid IS NOT NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO `MYTABLE` VALUES (NEW.timesheetid,NEW.punchingcode, NEW.date, NEW.time, NEW.Tid);
 delete from `tblt_timesheet` where Tid=1;

END IF;

END
```

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger in the trigger.

Comment: ok so is their a way to achieve the goal @P.Salmon

Comment: You are just deleting everything from tbl_timesheet where id = 1, there is no reference to what is being insert so why not wrap the insert and delete in a transaction